# Update firebase database after specific time

Tags: android, firebase

I have a data field and time field ,user Enter data and time
After Writing data on firebase realtime Database I want to reset data field and Time Field to 0 after The specifed time in Time Field

I read about cloud function but I don't know to solve my problem

I'm new to firebase and it's cloud function Please help...

Data field will contain somedata
Time Field Will Contain data like 20 ,30 or 40 which represent time in mins
so after writing both to database 
say if time field contain 20 ,so after 20 min to writing data in database, it should be reset to 0

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are new to Firebase, Cloud Functions is not the easiest way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you describe could be achieved in two ways. In my opinion, one can be cheaper and easier (no function involved but need to add some logic and a query to data on client side) if you could implement it which depends on your case.

Not the cheapest one: Schedule (cron type jobs) to scan your database regularly and check for the specified time and reset your data if condition is met. And this requires you to use Firebase functions and cron type services to configure it.

The cheaper way (although dependent on your case) in my mind would be to set your logic client side, so whenever a user is navigating to that data , check for the time and if condition is met reset the data client side without client noticing. This way, you don't need to set up functions, and you are not performing anything as long as no client has gone there (wherever that the data your mentioned is used in your app) Just keep in mind that this depends on whether you can have such scenario or your data has to be update regardless of users interaction with it. I have managed to redesign stuff whenever I have come across a case that needs periodic updates, etc.

**More info on second option:** 
Imagine your users are checking for an order which can expire after some time. Your intention is to reset data when expiry time has arrived. Instead of resetting data via functions, etc, you can write logic so that whenever a client queries the orders, you check for expiry time and if expired, you perform what has to be done there and then, in addition to making sure your client won't see the expired order. Hope this makes it more clear. It's sort of a passive way of updating your data in db.

Comment: can you elaborate on 2nd method cron type of jobs ,i certainly can't use client side logic

Comment: @Antony I added more info